# Is there a wildcard character in Express.js routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to create a web application structure like the following:

```
rootUrl/shopRecords/shop1
rootUrl/shopRecords/shop2
rootUrl/shopRecords/shop3...
```

where there can be any limit of shops, but all of the shop pages will have the same page layout (same HTML/Pug page, just populated with different data from a database). These URLs will be accessed from a list of buttons/links on a home page.

Does Express.js have a wildcard character so that I can specify behavior for all pages with link format `rootUrl/shopRecords/*` to be the same?

Comment: Yes, you can use `rootUrl/shopRecords/:shopId` and then access the property via `req.params.shopId`. But this is a very basic question and you can get the answer in first page of official documentation

Comment: @CristianTraìna — No, that is for query strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) section of the ExpressJS documentation.

> Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the
>   values specified at their position in the URL. The captured values are
>   populated in the `req.params` object, with the name of the route
>   parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.
>
> Route path: `/users/:userId/books/:bookId`
>  Request URL:
>   `http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989`
>  req.params: `{ "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }`
>
> To define routes with route parameters, simply specify the route
>   parameters in the path of the route as shown below.
>
> ```
> app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
>   res.send(req.params)
> })
> ```